# Help understanding proof involving smooth functions of compact support

Tags: real-analysis

In the following proof

[image]

I'm having trouble with two things:

1. Why the initial test function $\eta$ should be chosen to have integral $=1$.
2. How we know $\psi$ is smooth of compact support.

I'm guessing these two are related (the first is needed in order for the second to hold), but neither are explained in the proof.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two questions are related: Assume $\phi(x)=0$ for $x\notin [c, d] \subset (a,b)$, then for $e>d$,

$$\psi (e) = \int_a^e \phi(t) - A\eta(t)dt = \int_a^b \phi (t) dt - A\int_a^b \eta(t)dt =A\bigg(1- \int_a^b \eta(t)dt\bigg)\ .$$

That's why we need to choose such $\eta$. Note $\psi'(x) = \phi(x) - A\eta(x)$, $\psi$ is also smooth.

Comment: Thank you. This may be obvious, but I don't see why we want $\psi$ to be zero on these points? As for the second question, I see that $\psi'$ is smooth of compact support, because its the difference of two functions that are, but how does this imply $\psi$ itself is? Really appreciate the help.

Comment: In the equation of my answer, it shows that $\phi(e)=0$ if the integral of $\eta$ is 1. On the other hand, there is $c$ such that $\eta(x) = \phi(x) = 0$ for all $x<c$, as both of them are of compact support. This means $\psi(x) = 0$ for all $x<c$. Then $\psi$ is of compact support.

Comment: Got it, thanks!